# _beginthreadex() returns valid handle and crashes when executing thread using Codeblocks/Mingw with GNU GCC Compiler

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, mingw

I have a problem with my C Programm using Codeblocks/Mingw with the GNU GCC Compiler under a Windows environment.

I'm trying to implement a TCP-Server library, which alows to create and manage multiple servers simultanously.

I created some structures to manage the Servers:

```
typedef struct
{
  BOOL bExitThread;
  HANDLE hThread;
}TagThreadControl;

typedef struct
{
  SOCKET sSocket;
  int iMaxReceiveLengthPerMessage;
  struct in_addr tagIPAddress;
  USHORT usPort;
  TagThreadControl tagThread;
  TagQueue *ptagReveivedMessages;
}TagConnection_Internal;

typedef struct
{
  BOOL bInternalProcessingActive;
  UINT uiID;
  SOCKET sSocket;
  TagConnection_Internal *ptagConnections;
  WSADATA tagWsa;
  struct sockaddr_in tagServerInfo;
  TagThreadControl tagThreadGetNewConnections;
  int iMaxBacklog;
  int iMaxConnections;
  int iConnectionCount;
}TagServer;
```

Anyway, atm I'm focussing on just bringing a single one to run, and I occured a problem with using the function _beginthreadex. When I call it, it returns a valid handle (!NULL) and crashes internally when starting the thread. A new Server is created using the following function:

```
UINT uiTCPServer_Init_g(unsigned short usDestinationPort,
                        int iMaxReceiveLengthPerMessage,
                        int iMaxConnectionsCount,
                        int iMaxBacklogCount)
{
  UINT uiNewID;
  int iIndex;
  WSADATA tagWsa;

  /* First Server */
  if(iServerCount_m==0)
  {
    if(!bIDGenerator_Init_g(100))
    {
      printf("bIDGenerator_Init_g(): failed\n");
      return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);
    }
    if(!bIDGenerator_GetNewID_g(&uiNewID))
    {
      printf("bIDGenerator_GetNewID_g(): failed\n");
      return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);
    }
    printf("Got ID: %d\n",uiNewID);
    if(!(ptagServer_m=malloc(sizeof(TagServer))))
      return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);

    if(!(ptagServer_m->ptagConnections=malloc(sizeof(TagConnection_Internal)*iMaxConnectionsCount)))
    {
      return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);
    }
    /* Winsock DLL initislisieren */
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&tagWsa)!= 0)
    {
      printf("Init failed with error: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
      return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);
    }
    printf("Initialised\n");
  }
  else
  {
    //TODO: Implement list, for multiple servers
    printf("**NOT IMPLEMENTED!**\n");
    return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);
  }
  for(iIndex=0;iIndex<iMaxConnectionsCount;++iIndex)
    ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].ptagConnections[iIndex].iMaxReceiveLengthPerMessage=iMaxReceiveLengthPerMessage;

  /* Create Socket for listening.. */
  if((ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].sSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    printf("uiTCPServer_Init_g(): Failed to create Socket: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    if(iServerCount_m==0)
      WSACleanup();
    return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);
  }
  printf("Socket created\n");   // TODO: remove this

  ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].tagServerInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
  ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].tagServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].tagServerInfo.sin_port = htons(usDestinationPort);

  ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].iMaxBacklog=iMaxBacklogCount;
  ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].iMaxConnections=iMaxConnectionsCount;

  /* Socket binden */
  if(bind(ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].sSocket,
          (struct sockaddr*)&ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].tagServerInfo,
          sizeof(ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].tagServerInfo)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    printf("Bind failed: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
    if(iServerCount_m==0)
      WSACleanup();
    return(INVALID_SERVER_HANDLE);
  }
  printf("Bind done\n");   // TODO: remove this
  ptagServer_m[iServerCount_m].uiID=uiNewID;
  ++iServerCount_m;

  return(uiNewID);
```

Here's the Function called after the creation, which is crashing on calling _beginthreadex:

```
BOOL bTCPServer_StartListening_g(UINT uiServerID)
{
UINT uiThreadID;
TagServer *ptagCurrServer=ptagGetServerByID_m(uiServerID);
if(!ptagCurrServer)
  return(FALSE);

/* Start listen on socket */
if(listen(ptagCurrServer->sSocket,
          ptagCurrServer->iMaxBacklog) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
  printf("listen(): failed\n");
  return(FALSE);
}
printf("listen on socket started...\n");   // TODO: remove this
ptagCurrServer->tagThreadGetNewConnections.bExitThread=FALSE;
if(!(ptagCurrServer->tagThreadGetNewConnections.hThread=(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,
                                                                               0,
                                                                               &Thread_GetNewConnections_m,
                                                                               (void*)ptagCurrServer,
                                                                               0,
                                                                               &uiThreadID)))
{
  printf("_beginthreadex(): failed starting Thread_GetNewConnections_m");
  return(FALSE);
}
printf("_beginthreadex() returned valid handle\n");   // TODO: remove this
Sleep(2000); //Without that Sleep, returns successful and crashes after
printf("started listening thread\n");   // TODO: remove this
return(TRUE);
}
```

The Function called in the new Thread looks as follows:

```
unsigned __stdcall Thread_GetNewConnections_m(void *pvParam)
{
TagServer *ptagCurrServer=(TagServer*)pvParam;
struct sockaddr_in tagClientInfo;
int iSocketSize=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
int iFreeConnectionIndex;
UINT uiThreadID;

if(!ptagCurrServer)
{
  printf("Thread_GetNewConnections_m(): Terminated in an unusual way\n");
  return(0);
}
printf("started Thread_GetNewConnections_m()...\n");   // TODO: remove this
memset(ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections,0,sizeof(TagConnection_Internal)*ptagCurrServer->iMaxConnections);
while(!ptagCurrServer->tagThreadGetNewConnections.bExitThread)
{
  printf("Getnewcons...\n");   // TODO: remove this
  vCleanUpDeadConnections_m(ptagCurrServer);
  // TODO: clean up dead connections here...
  if(ptagCurrServer->iConnectionCount >= ptagCurrServer->iMaxConnections)
  {
    printf("Max Connections reached\n");
    Sleep(100);
    continue;
  }
  if((iFreeConnectionIndex=iTCPServer_GetNextFreeConnectionIndex_m(ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections,ptagCurrServer->iMaxConnections)) <0)
  {
    printf("iTCPServer_GetNextFreeConnectionIndex_m(): failed (Should not happen)\n");
    Sleep(100);
    continue;
  }
  printf("next free connection index: %d\n",iFreeConnectionIndex);
  if((ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections[iFreeConnectionIndex].sSocket=accept(ptagCurrServer->sSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&tagClientInfo,&iSocketSize)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    printf("accept(): failed\n");   // TODO: Don't return, handle error somehow
    Sleep(10);
    continue;
  }
  printf("New connection established\n");
  ++ptagCurrServer->iConnectionCount;
  /* Store Data from client */
  memcpy(&ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections[iFreeConnectionIndex].tagIPAddress,&tagClientInfo.sin_addr,sizeof(struct in_addr));
  ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections[iFreeConnectionIndex].usPort=ntohs(tagClientInfo.sin_port); //Convert form Network to host short
  /* Start Thread for new Connection */
  if((ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections[iFreeConnectionIndex].tagThread.hThread=(HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL,
                                                                                                     0,
                                                                                                     Thread_ConnectionHandler_m,
                                                                                                     &ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections[iFreeConnectionIndex],
                                                                                                     0,
                                                                                                     &uiThreadID))==NULL)
  {
    printf("_beginthreadex(): failed to start Thread for new connection\n");
    --ptagCurrServer->iConnectionCount;
    closesocket(ptagCurrServer->ptagConnections[iFreeConnectionIndex].sSocket);
    Sleep(100);
    continue;
  }
  Sleep(10);
}
return(0);
}
```

Funny thing is, whenever I comment the whole code (excluding the return(0)) in this function and just leave a printf() there, the programm still crashes, without even entering the function. I've included the following header files, and some created myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
```

If I try to run my compiled programm, the Trace looks as follows:

```
Curr index 0 (0), used: FALSE
Got ID: 1
Initialised
Socket created
Bind done
listen on socket started...
_beginthreadex() returned valid handle
```

Are there any additional compiler flags/header files, ... needed using Threads?

If more information is needed, just let me know.

Regards, XXXBold

Comment: You might need to compile/link with the -mthreads flag.

Comment: @rubenvb Thanks for your answer, I just added that option to my projects compiler options, but still get the same result as before.

Comment: What does "gcc -v" output?

Comment: @rubenv http://pastebin.com/ndvsWLL1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, another function with wrong call of malloc() corrupted the memory, could solve the problem using [Dr Memory](http://www.drmemory.org/)

Comment: Your autoanswer looks suspiciously like a spam seed.

Comment: No worries, it's not. Guess in future I should take more care of being more specific, but since it's another part of the code which I didn't post in the beginning, it would be a bit confusing imho.